# Spark and javax.crypto

Tags: scala, apache-spark, encryption, aes, javax.crypto

I am trying to learn about encryption and I came up with the following code

```
import java.util.Base64
object JavaCryptoEncryption{

  val Algorithm = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"
  val IvSpec = new IvParameterSpec(new Array[Byte](16))

  def encrypt(text: String, b64secret: String): String = {
    val cipher = Cipher.getInstance(Algorithm)
    val key = new SecretKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder.decode(b64secret), "AES")
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, IvSpec)

    new String(Base64.getEncoder.encode(cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes("utf-8"))), "utf-8")
  }

  def decrypt(text: String, b64secret: String): String = {
    val cipher = Cipher.getInstance(Algorithm)
    val key = new SecretKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder.decode(b64secret), "AES")
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, IvSpec)

    new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder.decode(text.getBytes("utf-8"))), "utf-8")
  }
}
```

Elsewhere in my system I define and store the key. I then apply `JavaCryptoEncryption.encrypt` and `JavaCryptoEncryption.decrypt` to a String value and it works fine. However, when I want to convert them to UDFs and apply to a column of a DataFrame I get `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable` . A similar code (without iv) works for AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding. Do certain modes don't support parallelism? Is there a way around? Or maybe there's a different reason?

Comment: Can you please provide your full stack trace error?

Comment: As a matter of fact, I'm going to edit the question as some progress has been made.

Comment: IvParameterSpec is indeed not serializable. Maybe if you try making the entire JavaCryptoEncryption class serializable, will that help? class JavaCryptoEncryption extends Serializable {

Comment: Sadly that doesn't help. I can only think of extracting the column to a sequence, iteration over it and reattaching to the original DataFrame. Do you happen to have other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're creating `IvParameterSpec` instance on the driver, and then Spark is trying to serialize it and sent to the executors (where all UDFs are actually executed). Maybe, try putting all object-creation-related code inside UDF itself, and just provide your key as a UDF parameter? That way you'll need to send only a `String` to workers, so there shouldn't be a serialization problem.